# How to output the test command Ginkgo uses

Tags: go, ginkgo

I have a Ginkgo test suite that has many test files.
I can run all tests under the test suite with the following command, where `./controller` is the package that has all tests.

```
go test ./controllers/... -v --args --ginkgo.vv
```

say ./controller folder has the following files

```
add_pods.go
add_pods_test.go
update_status.go
update_status_test.go
```

I want to figure out how to run update_status_test.go alone.
The `go test ./controller -run update_status`  doesn't work because it cannot find any test.

Can I let ginkgo output the `go test` command it uses to run each test?
That can give me hint on how to focus on a single test to run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes following to documentation (using ginkgo 1.16.5). Using options `-x go test` will display the `go test` command to run (`-n go test` also does it without running tests).

```bash
ginkgo help

...
-x go test
Have go test print the commands.
...
-n go test
Have go test print the commands but do not run them.
```

Comment: It seems that these are not available with Ginkgo 2.13